# JPA al realizar una query a una tabla me retorna elementos duplicados

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Actualmente tengo un problema al hacer un método en JPA, la respuesta se duplica cuando hago una query a una entidad que contiene 2 listas.

Entidad.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inscription")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Inscription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private int registryNumber;

    private int pageNumber;

    private String address;

    private String year;

    private String roleProperty;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = Nature.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_nature")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Nature nature;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Person.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Person> firstPerson;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Person.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Person> secondPerson;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private User registeredUser;

}
```

Entidad Persona

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String fullName;

    private String dni;


}
```

Repositorio

```
@Repository
public interface InscriptionRepository extends JpaRepository<Inscription, Long> {

    Page<Inscription> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    Page<Inscription> findAllByRoleProperty(Pageable pageable, String roleProperty);

    Page<Inscription> findAllByFirstPersonDniContainsOrSecondPersonDniContains(Pageable pageable, String dni, String dni2);

    Page<Inscription> findAllByFirstPersonFullNameContainsOrSecondPersonFullNameContains(Pageable pageable, String fullname, String fullname2);

    //Page<Inscription> findAllByFirstPersonFullNameContains(Pageable pageable, String fullname);
    //Page<Inscription> findAllBySecondPersonFullNameContains(Pageable pageable, String fullname);


}
```

Cuando llamo al repository

```
         case "TEST2":
                    inscriptionPage = inscriptionRepository.findAllByFirstPersonFullNameContainsOrSecondPersonFullNameContains(paging, filter, filter);
                    break;
```

Esta respuesta obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el JSON de respuesta donde se aprecian los elementos duplicados.

```
{
    "inscriptionList": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "registryNumber": 1,
            "pageNumber": 2,
            "address": "Los tineos 140",
            "year": "2022",
            "roleProperty": "SASD-123",
            "nature": {
                "id": 3,
                "nature": "Edit3",
                "nameFirstPerson": "Primera Persona",
                "nameSecondPerson": "Segunda Persona"
            },
            "firstPerson": [
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "fullName": "bbb",
                    "dni": "01"
                },
                {
                    "id": 67,
                    "fullName": "ccc",
                    "dni": "02"
                }
            ],
            "secondPerson": [
                {
                    "id": 68,
                    "fullName": "ddd",
                    "dni": "03"
                }
            ],
            "registeredUser": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "jorge",
                "email": "jorge@icloud.com",
                "statusActive": true,
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "registryNumber": 1,
            "pageNumber": 2,
            "address": "Los tineos 140",
            "year": "2022",
            "roleProperty": "SASD-123",
            "nature": {
                "id": 3,
                "nature": "Edit3",
                "nameFirstPerson": "Primera Persona",
                "nameSecondPerson": "Segunda Persona"
            },
            "firstPerson": [
                {
                    "id": 66,
                    "fullName": "bbb",
                    "dni": "01"
                },
                {
                    "id": 67,
                    "fullName": "ccc",
                    "dni": "02"
                }
            ],
            "secondPerson": [
                {
                    "id": 68,
                    "fullName": "ddd",
                    "dni": "03"
                }
            ],
            "registeredUser": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "jorge",
                "email": "jorge@icloud.com",
                "statusActive": true,
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "ROLE_ADMIN"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "currentPage": 1,
    "totalItems": 2,
    "totalPages": 1
}
```

Esto me pasa cuando la búsqueda que hago se encuentra en el atributo secondPerson de la entidad(Le pase un fullName = "bbb"), ya que cuando hago esta misma búsqueda y el fullName lo encuentra en firstPerson responde solo un elemento.

Saben que podría estar ocurriendo?

Comment: Encontraste alguna solucion? Tengo justo el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no te esta cogiendo el segundo parametro en tu metodo.
Probaría a cambiar el query method por otro nombre como por ejemplo:

```
Page<Inscription> findAllByFirstPersonFullNameContainsOrSecondPersonDniContains(Pageable pageable, String fullname, String dni);
```

si el problema esta en como detecta el query method los parametros lo mejor seria escribirlo como un @Query.

Comment: Si lo toma, ya que cuando quiero hacer la búsqueda por "secondPerson" me trae registros duplicados